# Fetching Exact matching rows only From mariadb table

Tags: mysql, string, count, mariadb, having-clause

I have a table like below

```
Create Table tmp_test (
    id int(11) unsigned Auto_increment primary key , 
    contract_id int(11) unsigned, 
    item_id int(11) unsigned
);

Insert Into tmp_test (contract_id,item_id)
Values (10,1),(10,2),(10,3),(12,1),(12,2),(14,1),
(16,1),(16,2),(16,3),(16,4),(18,1),(18,2),(20,1),
(20,2),(20,3),(22,2),(22,3),(22,4),(24,1),(24,4);
```

When we select Query

1.
Select Distinct contract_id
From tmp_test
Where FIND_IN_SET(item_id, '1,2');

OutPut Need to

```
12, 18
```

2. ```
     Select Distinct contract_id 
     From tmp_test 
     Where FIND_IN_SET(item_id, '1');
   ```

OutPut Need to

```
14
```

3. ```
     Select Distinct contract_id 
     From tmp_test 
     Where FIND_IN_SET(item_id, '1,2,3');
   ```

OutPut Need to

```
10, 20
```

4. ```
     Select Distinct contract_id 
     From tmp_test 
     Where FIND_IN_SET(item_id, '4,1');
   ```

OutPut Need to

```
24
```

Please help me to achieve this in single query

Regards,

Faisal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select contract_id From (
Select contract_id,group_concat(item_id order By item_id) items From tmp_test 
Group By contract_id  ) sb
Where items Like '1,2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `contract_id`s that have all the values of the input list, and no other.

You could phrase this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select contract_id
from tmp_test
group by item_id
having sum(item_id in (1, 2)) = 2 and sum(item_id not in (1, 2)) = 0
```

Or if you prefer `find_in_set()`:

```
having sum(find_in_set(item_id, '1,2')) = 2 and sum(find_in_set(item_id, '1,2') = 0) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer, When i try your query, i didn't get any response. Output is empty.